# CSS border doesn't work

Tags: html, css

***HTML:***

```
<body>
    <div><p>Something</p></div>
    <div class = "myPanel">
        <div class = "heading">my header</div>
        <div class = "body">my body</div>
    </div>
    <div><p>Something</p></div>
</body>
```

***css:***

```
.myPanel: {
    border: 1px solid #687D6D;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 1px black;
    margin: 3%;
}
.myPanel .heading {
    background: #B6F0C4;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #687D6D;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.myPanel .body {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sUtvd/620/)

What I'm curious is that, even if I set `border` on `.myPanel`, it doesn't work on `.myPanel .body`, there's no border around `.myPanel .body`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is your problem:

```
.myPanel: {
```

just remove the **:** (colon)

snippet below:

```css
.myPanel {
  border: 1px solid #687D6D;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 1px black;
  margin: 3%;
}
.myPanel .heading {
  background: #B6F0C4;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #687D6D;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.myPanel .body {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Something</p>
</div>
<div class="myPanel">
  <div class="heading">my header</div>
  <div class="body">my body</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Something</p>
</div>
```